# Problem with choosing のは or は with と思います

Tags: usage, particle-は, particle-の, nominalization

So in my textbook there are examples like

> あまり便利じゃないと思います
> いいと思います

But I was wondering, how would you say something like "I think it's ok to eat food". From my knowledge it should be something along the lines of:

> 食べ物を食べるはいいと思います

But I'm certain that this is not okay, any help is appreciated.

Comment: 食べる is a verb.  To make it the topic of a sentence marked by は, you need to nominalize it:  you do that by putting something like の, こと, or もの after it.  In this case, の would be the most straight-forward.

Answer (score 5):

The issue of choosing between のは and は has little to nothing to do with と思います.

The grammar of these constructs is as follows:

- <*sentence*> と思います
- <*noun phrase*> は

In your first two examples:

> あまり便利じゃないと思います

The *sentence* is あまり便利じゃない:  "it is not very useful".

> いいと思います

The *sentence* is いい:  "It is good".

Notice that even in English with "I think it's ok to eat food", the "to eat food" is itself not a sentence.  It's a noun phrase formed from an infinite of the verb "eat".  (In English we might say "the verb to eat" but this is technically not correct.)

If you have some sort of verbal phrase that you want to say something about, you've first got to nominalize it.  Most frequently you will choose one of either こと or の.  Once the verbal phrase is nomialized you can put it in a sentence and refer to it like you would just about any other noun.

> 食べ物を食べる

This means, "Someone eats food".

> 食べ物を食べるの

This means, "To eat food" (an infinitive phrase in English) or "Eating food" (a gerund construction in English).  Now we can say something about "eating food".

> 食べ物を食べるのはいい

It's good/OK to eat food.

And now you can tack on と思います to get the idea in there that this is what you think.

> 食べ物を食べるのはいいと思います

Answer (score 4):

What @A.Ellett says is right and probably the easiest solution, i.e.

> 食べ物を食べるのはいいと思います。

is perfectly fine. However, maybe it's important to keep in mind that this phrase sounds like there are other things which are forbidden, like "it's forbidden to take a photo, talk on the phone, but it's ok to eat food", which is caused by the particle "は". If you want to make a neutral phrase, it might be better to say:

> 食べ物を食べてもいいと思います。